# How to use NSTableView's selectedRowIndexes?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nstableview

I'm just learning some basic programming in Objective C and Cocoa. I'm trying to get some data from NSTableView. Based on what I read in one tutorial, I wrote this:

```
NSArray * items = [[itemsTableView selectedRowEnumerator] allObjects];
```

But then I learned that `selectedRowEnumerator` was deprecated already in 10.3 Panther and that I should use `selectedRowIndexes`.

The problem is, I didn't find how to actually use the returned `NSIndexSet` to achieve the same result as with code written above.

So, If anyone could give me a tip, I would be very grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the indexes of an `NSIndexSet` like this:

```
- (void) goThroughIndexSet:(NSIndexSet *) anIndexSet
{
    NSUInteger idx = [anIndexSet firstIndex];

    while (idx != NSNotFound)
    {
        // do work with "idx"
        NSLog (@"The current index is %u", idx);

        // get the next index in the set
        idx = [anIndexSet indexGreaterThanIndex:idx];
    }

    // all done
}
```

Comment: There's also various 10.6-only methods involving blocks, but I haven't gone near blocks because I always need to support 10.4 as a minimum :(

Comment: Well, I've actually found a more elegant solution to my problem, but thanks for your time :)

As for the blocks: Don't they work on 10.5 Leopard too? 'Cause I feel I've read somewhere that they were back-ported.

Comment: Jakub Lédl: You should also look at the documentation for the NSIndexSet class. Every Cocoa and Cocoa Touch class has a page documenting its public interface. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexSet_Class/

Answer (score 2):

To illustrate most clearly,

```
    NSIndexSet *selectedRows = [MyTableView selectedRowIndexes];
    NSUInteger numberOfSelectedRows = [selectedRows count];
    NSUInteger indexBuffer[numberOfSelectedRows];

    NSUInteger limit = [selectedRows getIndexes:indexBuffer maxCount:numberOfSelectedRows inIndexRange:NULL];

    for (unsigned iterator = 0; iterator < limit; iterator++)
    {
        MyObject  *object = [ myDataSource objectAtIndex:indexBuffer[iterator] ];

        NSLog(@"Object at index: %lu", (unsigned long) indexBuffer[iterator] );
        NSLog(@"Object selected: %@", [object description]);
    }
```